# Why is Java MousePressed invoked twice for one mouse press?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I am testing a simple java graphics program using Eclipse on Mac OSX with the following code:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.print("Mouse is pressed \n\n");
}
```

However, whenever I press the mouse, the method seems to be invoked twice, as it prints the line twice. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Could it be that you registered the listener twice?

Comment: Well, I only use addMouseListeners() once

Comment: It's no use guessing, anyway. Without some real code from you, it could be anything.

Comment: Well, mousePressed method and main method are the only two methods in the code. In main, there is nothing but addMouseListeners().

Comment: Have you tried running the demo http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: Yep, it runs well....now it really looks strange...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it by removing the MouseListener like this:

```
component.removeMouseListener(component);
```

after that my code worked fine.